# I initialized a number, I concatenated it in an html string, but it doesn't work

Tags: php, html

I've been trying to make a "ranking" system. Where the first on a table is 1 then the second is 2; I've semi done this but I'm having issues.

```php
do {
   echo "The number is ".$i."<br/>";
   $i++;
} 
while ($i <= 5);

        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
             $uuid = $row['UUID'];
             $kills = $row['KILLS'];
             $deaths = $row['DEATHS'];
             $wins = $row['WINS'];
             $points = $row['POINTS'];
             $crystals = $row['CRYSTALS'];
             echo
             "<tr>
               <td>The number is ".$i."</td>
```

That is my current code, and here's the output:
[image: My leaderboards]

So, it works outside the table, but once in the table seems to keep the same value. I was thinking maybe that is because the whole table is set on one preset row, but it worked fine with other php related things, so why wouldn't it work with this?

Comment: you're not increasing `$i` anywhere. Change `<td>The number is ".$i."</td>` to `<td>The number is ".$i++."</td>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the code right, just had to increase the number within the table by editing this:

```php
<td>".$i."</td>
```

To this:

```php
<td>".$i++."</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

First set your $i to 0 then increase the value for every while turn, Here is edited code:

```
do {
   echo "The number is ".$i."<br/>";
   $i++;
} 
while ($i <= 5);

$i = 0;
        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ){
             $i++;
             $uuid = $row['UUID'];
             $kills = $row['KILLS'];
             $deaths = $row['DEATHS'];
             $wins = $row['WINS'];
             $points = $row['POINTS'];
             $crystals = $row['CRYSTALS'];
             echo
             "<tr>
               <td>The number is ".$i."</td>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, although my issue was inside the table, not the increment being high. All good now.